# ¿Cómo notificar 'Click' en link de un Control .ASCX en una pagina .ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tengo un control con el siguiente link puesto en el fichero MiControl.ascx
:

```
<a ID="Link1" href="#" runat="server" OnServerClick="Link1_Click">Ir a enlace</a>
```

En el fichero MiControl.ascx.cs:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonLinkClick;


protected void Link1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ButtonLinkClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

En la pagina Principal.aspx:

```
<@ Register src="MiControl.ascx" tagname="MiControl" tagPrefix="uc1">

<uc1:MiControl ID="Micontrol1" runat="server" OnButtonLinkClick="MiControl1_ButtonLinkClicked" />
```

en .ASPX.CS:

```
protected void MiControl1_ButtonLinkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Mi código 
}
```

Cuando hago "Click" en el control llamado MiControl debería ejecutarse el código que hay dentro de MiControl1_ButtonLinkClicked pero lo único que obtengo es un error en el explorador de este tipo:

```
Error: '__doPostBack' no esta definido
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que pulsando en el link del MiControl llegue una notificación a la pagina principal.aspx y ejecute el código que me interesa ?

Answer (score 0):

Después de muchas pruebas he detectado el error. El control .ascx debe ir dentro de una etiqueta  y con el componente . De todas maneras me gustaría saber si es posible hacer lo mismo con "delegados" enviando una notificación a otro control o a la pagina.